# Query to get the sum of values for the maximum number of months

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

This query in Oracle 11 gets the sum of value for the last 1 years, and it works when there are 1 years of data.

When there is less than 1 years of data, this query returns 0, instead of the sum of values until whatever the oldest years are.

For example, if there are only 6 months of data, the query should return the sum of values until the 6th month.

```
SELECT SUM (DECODE (rnk, 11, rt, 0)) 1Y
FROM (SELECT entity_id,rnk,
             SUM (ABS(NVL (value, 0))) OVER (PARTITION BY TRIM (entity_id) ORDER BY rnk) rt
      FROM (SELECT psm.*,RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY entity_id ORDER BY period_end_date DESC) AS rnk
            FROM myTable psm
            WHERE psm.entity_id = '1'
            ORDER BY period_end_date DESC
           ) rank_tab
      WHERE rnk < 12
      );
```

If the biggest rank is 6, the result from the above query is 0

I attempted this, but got the error "ORA-00978: nested group function without GROUP BY"

```
SELECT case when rnk < 11
                 then SUM (DECODE (rnk, Max(rnk), rt, 0))
            else SUM (DECODE (rnk, 11, rt, 0)) 
       end as Y
FROM (SELECT entity_id,rnk,
             SUM (ABS(NVL (value, 0))) OVER (PARTITION BY TRIM (entity_id) ORDER BY rnk) rt
      FROM (SELECT psm.*,RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY entity_id ORDER BY period_end_date DESC) AS rnk
            FROM myTable psm
            WHERE psm.entity_id = '1'
            ORDER BY period_end_date DESC
           ) rank_tab
      WHERE rnk < 12
     );
```

Sample data:

```
entity_id   value   period_end_date 
1           1       9/30/19
1           2       8/31/19
1           3       7/31/19
1           4       6/30/19
1           5       5/31/19
1           6       4/30/19
```

In the above example, 1Y should return 1+2+3+4+5+6 = 21.
Instead my query returns 0 because it is looking for rnk = 11, which doesn't exist.

```
SUM (DECODE (rnk, 11, rt, 0)) 1Y
```

Thank you.

EDIT:

This works. But, if you know of a better way to do it, please let me know. Thank you.

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN MRank < 11 then maxY else OneY end as lc_incearned_1Y
FROM (
WITH R as
(SELECT MAX(RNK) MaxRank FROM (
SELECT RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY TRIM (entity_id) ORDER BY period_end_date 
DESC) AS rnk FROM myTbl psm
WHERE TRIM (psm.entity_id) = '1' AND period_end_date < 
to_date('9/30/2019','MM/DD/YYYY')
ORDER BY period_end_date DESC))
select MAX(MaxRank) MRank,
SUM (DECODE (rnk, MaxRank, rt, 0)) maxY,
SUM (DECODE (rnk, 11, rt, 0)) OneY,  --13051.97
FROM (SELECT entity_id,rnk,
SUM (ABS (NVL (value, 0))) OVER (PARTITION BY TRIM (entity_id) ORDER BY rnk) rt
FROM (SELECT psm.*,RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY TRIM (entity_id) ORDER BY period_end_date DESC) AS rnk FROM CREF.PORTFOLIO_SUMM_MTHEND psm
WHERE TRIM (psm.entity_id) = '1' AND period_end_date < to_date('9/30/2019','MM/DD/YYYY')
ORDER BY period_end_date DESC) rank_tab WHERE rnk < 12) T,R)
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results and a clear explanation of the logic would all help.

Comment: I have added sample data and desired results.

Comment: @faujong, Do you need only the last 11 months data from the current date or the last 11 rows of data?

Comment: Did you just try a simple `SUM()` without the `RANK` subquery? You can put the id and date constraints inside the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: I need the sum of the last 11 month data.

Comment: I just edited my post with code that works. 
But, if you have any better way to do it, please let me know.
THank you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to sum your values up starting from the latest period_end_date to the earliest date within the eleven months range. It would be suitable to use `max(period_end_date) over (partition by entity_id order by period_end_date desc)` analytic function along with your current `rank()` function. And then apply `months_between(<max_period_end_date>,period_end_date)`. If your need to look up from the current date, then get rid of `max()` analytic function and replace `<max_period_end_date>` with `trunc(sysdate)` in `months_between()` function. So, use :

```
with t as
(
select max(period_end_date) over (partition by entity_id order by period_end_date desc) as mx,
       rank() over (partition by entity_id order by period_end_date desc) as rnk,
       t.*
  from myTable t
)
select sum(nvl(value,0)) as sum_value
  from t
 where months_between(mx,period_end_date)<=11
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=cc9d9d7c7ccb4a264aaa0691eb321a1a)</kbd>